# Foreach dentro de if Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, foreach

Tenho uma tabela A que armazena um item, e nessa tabela, tenho uma outra relacionada B que pode ter vários itens agregados á um item da tabela A.

Segue código do if:

```
if ($this->ClientePagamento->save($valor_pagar)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Valor adicionado com Sucesso');
            $id_valor = $this->ClientePagamento->id;
            foreach($moedas_ativas as $moeda){                    
                $itens_referentes = array(
                    'cliente_pagamento_id' => $id_valor,
                    'valor' => $moeda[key($moeda)]['valor_reais'],                                                
                );
                $this->ClientePagamentoItem->save($itens_referentes);
            }
```

Neste foreach são os itens que deveriam ser salvos, mas o foreach só roda uma vez e acaba salvando só o primeiro item, sendo que no array tem mais de 1 item. Isso é erro de semântica ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Acredito que faltou um `create` antes de salvar, algo assim: `$this->ClientePagamentoItem->create();`.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, valeu paulo..